# MySql left outer join with condiction

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, left-join

I have two tables as

```
    student_info(id,mobile,cTId,lvDate)

    term_marks(tmId,stdId,cTId,marks,year)
```

Now I want to find out the all student id that are not present term_marks depending other checking,
so I use this query but it returns all that matched and not matched two tables

```
     $sql = "select * from student_info si LEFT OUTER JOIN term_marks tm ON si.id=tm.stdId and si.cTId=tm.cTId AND tm.year=$year)
WHERE si.cTId=$cTId and si.lvDate=0";
```

Also I have tried it

```
      $sql = "select * from student_info si left outer JOIN term_marks tm where si.id=tm.stdId 
     and si.cTId=tm.cTId and si.cTId=$cTId and tm.year=$year and si.lvDate=0";
```

**Can you help me ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT si.* 
FROM student_info si 
WHERE si.cTId = $cTId 
  AND si.lvDate = 0
  AND si.id NOT IN 
  ( 
    SELECT tm.stdId 
    FROM term_marks tm 
    WHERE tm.year = $year
  )
```

Comment: But other condictions ??

Comment: is it possible ?
           $sql = "SELECT si.* FROM student_info si WHERE si.id NOT IN ( SELECT tm.stdId  FROM term_marks tm WHERE tm.year = $year )  and si.cTId=$cTId and si.lvDate=0";

Comment: There are tutorials all over the place.  Try searching for *SQL Tutorials* or *SQL JOIN Tutorials*.  Or a faster way would be to buy a highly rated and recent book about MySql.  Try searching Amazon for a good book.